# Как подключить скрипт node js к своему сайту на html?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, база-данных

У меня есть верстка на html и скрипт node.js, который подключается к Базе Данных Mysql, потом должен собирать данные с формы html и отправлять их в Базу Данных MySql. Сейчас скрипт работает при открытии его через термина. Как сделать чтобы при отправке формы(нажатии на кнопку) срабатывал скрипт node js и отправлял данные с формы в БД?

PS Попробовал в тупую подключить файл с скриптом node js перед  в файле HTML, но выдает ошибку connect.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.

Мой скрипт:

```css
const mysql = require('mysql');

const conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    database: "mysestbase",
    password: "root"
});


const name = document.querySelector('#signin_name').value;
const mail = document.querySelector('#signin_mail').value;
const phone = document.querySelector('#signin_phone').value;

document.querySelector('.signin-btn').addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    conn.connect(err => {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
            return err;
        }else{
            console.log("database --- ok");
        }
    });

    let query = "INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `Name`, `PhoneNum`, `Mail`) VALUES ('', '%name%', '%phone%', '%mail%');";
    query = query.replace('%name%', name);
    query = query.replace('%phone%', phone);
    query = query.replace('%mail%', mail);

    conn.query(query, (err, result)=>{
        console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
    });

    conn.end(err =>{
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
            return err;
        }else{
            console.log("database --- finished");
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js скрипты в html файле не подключить. Только JavaScript можно подключать в html. Node.js скрипты запускаются на сервере. Ваш сайт должен отправлять запрос на сервер с данными, серверный скрипт обрабатывать этот запрос взаимодействуя с базой данных или нет и отдавать ответ с данными на сайт.

По поводу ошибки ему требуется модуль mysql, который вы пытаетесь подключить в первой строке, но так как такого модуля у вас нет, то выходит ошибка. Модули обычно скачиваются для серверных скриптов на Node.js в папку node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm init
```

вставь это в терминал внутри проекта, это загрузит все модули в папку node_modules как было выше сказано